# Automatic token fetching with OAuth2 client_credentials flow with Python Requests

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, wrapper, clientcredential

I want to use an API that is authenticated with the `OAuth2` **client_credentials** flow from *Python*.

In pyhton the most widely used HTTP client is [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), and `Requests` has many advanced features and extensions, some of which revolve around using it with `OAuth2`.

However, Oauth2 is a complex beast that support 4 different flows, of which **client_credentials** is the simplest. Try as I might, I have not found a simple to-the-point example of using `Requests` with the **client_credentials** flow. It is always mentioned at the end of the article as a sidenote or afterthought after explaining all the othe flows in intricated detail.

In **client_credentials** flow, the following will happen:

### 1. POST the following encoded as **x-www-form-urlencoded** to the "token endpoint":

```
{
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "scope": "all", # Or whatever scope you care about
}
```

where the **client_id** and **client_secret** are provided by the service you are accessing.

### 2. The following will be returned as **json** (given the auth was successful):

```
{
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "scope":"openid email profile offline_access roles read:tickets read:customers ...",
    "access_token":"XXX_THIS_TOKEN_IS_VERY_SECRET_XXX"
}
```

### 3. Use "access_token" from returned data to access protected resources:

You use it by setting it in the `Authorization:` Bearer header in all requests to protected resources in the following way:

```
Authorization: Bearer XXX_THIS_TOKEN_IS_VERY_SECRET_XXX
```

The token will last **1 hour** from being generated and when a resource request returns 401 auth errors, simply repeat steps #1 and #2 to generate a new token to use.

My current code manually requests a token from the token endpoint, parses the token from the resulting json and stuffs that into subsequent requests' HTTP headers. I then proceed to detect 401 errors and re-authenticate. This works but it is very tediouos. I now have to wrap every request usage with this ugly mess.

I was hoping there would be a way to do it similar to this:

```
client = MagicRequestsWrapper(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, token_endpoint=token_endpoint, scope=scope)

res = client.get(protected_resource_endpoint)
```

where all the oauth stuff is now hidden and client behaves exactly like a normal Requests client.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the Oauth2 server URL?

Comment: @Bench Vuew It is the url to auth endpoint specified by the service you are authenticating with.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer shortly after writing this question.

```
import requests
from requests_oauth2client import OAuth2Client, OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuth

def oauth2_session(client_id, client_secret, base_url, scope="all"):
    token_url = f"{base_url}/auth/token" # This may be different for your endpoint

    oauth2client = OAuth2Client( token_endpoint=token_url, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
    auth = OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuth( oauth2client, scope=scope, resource=base_url)

    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = auth
    return session
```

Example usage as follows:

```
# Create a session
base_url = "https://myservice.com"
my_session = oauth2_session(client_id=os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID"), client_secret=os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET"), base_url=base_url)

# Use it as normal requests object to post and get
result = my_session.get(f"{base_url}/api/some_resource")

my_session.post(f"{base_url}/api/some_resource", json={"test":123})
```